# swprintf_s fails when writing to initialized buffer

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, stack-overflow, access-violation, printf

I am writing a program in C for windows using visual studio 2010. I am using the swprintf_s function to write a formatted string to a wchar_t buffer. 
I am getting the following errors when I attempt to write to a buffer that has been initialized.

```
Unhandled exception at 0x77b3fbda in svats.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow.
```

and sometimes

```
Unhandled exception at 0xfefefefe in svats.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.
```

Here is the code that produces the access violation.

```
wchar_t wBuff[1024] = L"b";
int test;
test = swprintf_s(wBuff,sizeof(wBuff),L"a%s","test");
```

and the code for the stack overflow.

```
wchar_t wBuff[1024] = L"b";
int test;
test = swprintf_s(wBuff,sizeof(wBuff),L"a%s",L"test");
```

Now the 2nd piece of code worked once, don't know why.

Anyone know what the problem is?

PS. These files aren't getting loaded, anyone know why? Is it because visual studio is 32 bit and my OS is 64 bit?

```
'svats.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'svats.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'svats.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'svats.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'svats.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'svats.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'svats.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'svats.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'svats.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'svats.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'svats.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'svats.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'svats.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'svats.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ws2_32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'svats.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nsi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'svats.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'svats.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
```

Comment: Maybe `sizeof(wBuff)` (2048 perhaps, or 4096) should be `sizeof wBuff/sizeof *wBuff` (1024) to indicate number of `wchar_t`s rather than bytes? ??

Comment: Thanks it works, could you explain why sizeof(wBuff) is 2048 instead of 1024 and what sizeof(*wBuff) is?

Comment: The type `wchar_t` is "wide char": it (very probably) occupies more than 1 byte (I believe it's 2 on Windows and 4 on Unixen). When you do `sizeof` you get the number of bytes, so an array of 1000 `wchar_t` occupies 2000 (or 4000) bytes. The size of each array element can be obtained with `sizeof element` (`sizeof wBuff[0]` is the same as `sizeof *wBuff`) and is 2 (or 4). 2000 divided by 2 gives the number of elements in the array. Apparently I just guessed correctly about `swprintf_s()` needing the number of elements :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
int main() {
  wchar_t wBuff[1024] = L"b";
  int test;
  test = swprintf_s(wBuff,_countof(wBuff),L"a%s","test");
}
```

This code would work instead. As stated by [pmg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25324/pmg), the second parameter should be 1024, not 2048. When you do sizeof, it will return the size in bytes. However `swprintf_s` expects the number of characters available in the buffer. You can either use `_countof` which essentially expands to the same as what has already been suggested to you.